# Имеется массив из изображений которые выводятся в сетку. но необходимо еще вывести и имена этих изображений

Tags: php

На мой сайт в галерею хочу вывести сетку с изображениями и их именами. Через html выводить 600+ изображения это как то неправильно, а вот через php изображения то вывел. Но как вывести их имена под ими?

```
<?php
            $directory = "../img";   
            $allowed_types=array("jpg", "png", "gif");  
            $file_parts = array();
            $ext="";
            $title="";
            $i=0;

            $dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("Ошибка при открытии папки !!!");
            while ($file = readdir($dir_handle))    
            {
                if($file=="." || $file == "..") continue; 
                $file_name = basename($directory,".png");
                $file_parts = explode(".",$file);          
                $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));   

                if(in_array($ext,$allowed_types))
                {
                    echo '<img src="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" class="pimg" title="'.$file.'" /><br><p>'+$file_name+'</p>';
                    $i++;
                }

            }
            closedir($dir_handle);  
            ?>
```

Comment: Так выводи `$file`

Comment: если вывожу переменную $file то в контейнере исчезают изображения и появляются только 000(три ноля)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй такой вариант:

```
$catalog = '../img/';
$all_files = glob("{$catalog}*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($all_files); ++$i)
{
    $image_name = $all_files[$i];
    $supported_format = ['gif','jpg','png'];

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $name_d[] = explode($catalog, $image_name)[1];

    if (in_array($ext, $supported_format)) {
        echo '
            <img src="'.$image_name.'" class="pimg" alt="'.$name_d[$i].'" />
            <br><p>'.$name_d[$i].'</p>
        ';
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо но есть еще вопрос. Как убрать формат файла? У меня там на фото номера таваров как и в журнале-каталоге

Comment: @АлексейНовожилов, вы о названии изображений? Или про какой формат идет речь?

Comment: название изображений. оно пишется в данный момент (название.png)

Comment: @АлексейНовожилов, можно использовать `preg_replace('~(.+)(?:\.(gif|jpg|png))~', '$1', $name_d[$i]);`